# Can I make python read a string as a parameter?

Tags: python, parameters

I would like to make this code somehow work, in this example i used the int() function which obviously gave me the "invalid literal for int() with base 10" error. But is there any way to make python not read the "" around the string and just read "i" in this case as a parameter.
I hope you understand what I mean.

```
s=0
w=""
for k in range(3):
    w+="i"
    for i in range(5):
        s+=int(w)
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: don't put " " quotes around i, if you want to concat i to w you can do it by `w += str(i)`

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know whats your expected result. Your main problems seems the quotes for w = "" and w+="i" if you want to add numbers instead of textstrings.

Maybe you also mixed up your k and i variable.

Is this your expected result(?):

```
s = 0
w = 0
for k in range(3):
    w += k
    for i in range(5):
        s += w

print(s)
print(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current version of code, when you say int(w) you are trying to convert 'iii' into a base 10 number which runs the error. Also, using i as a variable will only work within the for loop 'for i in range(5):'. That is where the variable i has its lifespan.